# Issues Firebase cloud function call third party API using node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I trying to write node function to call third party API . I using the angular Fire Function for display the results in angular project. The issues is no data response;

Here is my node js code.

```
const request = require('request');
const UserDetail =  () => {

    const options ={
        url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
            'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
        }
    }

    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        let json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json);
        
    });
     
}
UserDetail();
```

Here is my firebase function code:

```
exports.userdetails = functions.https.onRequest(require('./api/user/userdetail'));
```

Here is my angular service  calling firebase function code:

```
callUserDetails(){
         const details = this.functions.httpsCallable('userdetails')({ text: 'Some Request Data' })
         .pipe()
         .subscribe(resp => {
           console.log({ resp });
         }, err => {
           console.error({ err });
         });
          
  }
```

Comment: In your `UserDetail ()`, do you return anything from your `request`?

Comment: yes have return value when i run in node js no problems but  after i deploy to firebase run in angular have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTPS Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

By doing

```
exports.userdetails = functions.https.onRequest(...)
```

you define an HTTPS Cloud Function,

but by doing

```
this.functions.httpsCallable('userdetails')({ text: 'Some Request Data' })
```

in your front-end, you actually call a Callable Cloud Function.

---

You should either change your Cloud Function to a Callable one, or call the `userdetails` HTTPS Cloud Function by sending an HTTP Request to the Cloud Function URL.

I would advise the first approach because Callable brings several advantages over a "simmple" HTTPS one (see the doc).

---

In addition you need to note that `request` supports callback interfaces natively but does not return a Promise. And it is necessary to use Promises in order to manage the life cycle of a Callable Cloud Function (see the official [video serie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=4&t=1s)).

I would use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) along the following lines (untested):

```
exports.userdetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {

        const options = {
            url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json',
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
                'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
            }
        }

        const axiosResponse = await axios(options);

        // Build the resp to be sent to the frontend by 
        // using axiosResponse.data .... up to you, see https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

        return { resp: .... }

    } catch (error) {
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call angular service like this:

```
// provider class
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

this.http.get(url, {params: {}, headers: {}}).subscribe(result => {
  //// result 
})
```